# Question about uniform convergence of a series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have encountered a problem which I think is troublesome.

Let $g_n,g \in C^0 [a,b],n \ge 1$ such that $g_n,g$ are monotonically increasing functions. Let $X \subset [a,b]$ be an arbitrary dense subset of the interval $[a,b]$. Assume $a,b \in X$ and 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n (x) =g(x)$$
for any $x \in X$.Prove that $g_n$ converges to g uniformly on $[a,b]$.

This is a question that asks us to prove uniform convergence from pointwise convergences. The problem will be mistaken if we do not let $g$ be continuous. Consider $g_n = x^n$ on interval $[0,1]$, this is not true because $g(x)=\delta _{x1}$ and $g_n$ does not converges uniformly.

However, $g$ is continuous and i did not know where to start. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be a hint ... but by the time I made this picture, I forgot exactly how. Hope it help anyway :)

[image]

(Re your proposed counterexample, your $g$ is not continuous, and it is supposed to be.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited the question. Yet I am still struggling about it. The restrictions are very tricky and I can't pick a point to start.

Comment: perhaps you could use that $g$ is continuous on a compact interval, hence uniformly continuous. Given $\varepsilon>0$ this may help you pick finitely many points on the interval, all belonging to $X$ (including the two endpoints). You could pick $n$ large enough so that $g_n$ is close to $g$ at all these finitely many points. Then use that $g_n$ is monotone and think of this picture that looks like a stair, $g_n$ must be between the two stairs.

Comment: Oh I see! So because $g_n$must be located between two stairs and the gap is small than $\epsilon$, and also we pick finitely many stairs, the series converges to g uniformly. I think I got that. Thanks so much!

Comment: yes, though I didn't think of all details, and I know some care must be taken to make sure not only the red dots are near the graph, but also the green corners are near. Perhaps something along the lines work with $\varepsilon/3$ initially so in the end you could say something about $\varepsilon$ ... but I didn't work all details, it might be slightly more difficult or slightly easier than I think.